# question regarding inline functions in c++

Tags: c++, inline

`inline unsigned int FunctionName() const { return variable; }`

I recently came across inline functions, and i wanted to know what const is actually doing in this snippet of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is an method and inline is optional here. Const mean the this method do not change something in the struct/class. Also it mean that you can use it on const version of this struct/class.

```
struct my_stuff {
    int variable;

    inline int FunctionName() const { return variable; }
}
```